# Is "Stop agitating yourself, comfort yourself now!" grammarly correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence

"**Stop agitating yourself, comfort yourself now!**"

Is the sentence above have a *correct* grammar?

Comment: It's *syntactically* valid, but I'm not sure any native speaker would ever say it (mainly because of the second imperative, not the first).

Comment: A more natural expression would be: *Don't get worked up, relax.* Note too that using an exclamation mark at the end results in the opposite effect of what's trying to be expressed. Anybody who receives a *demand* to take comfort or relax will actually be stressed out by it.

Comment: No; never. The problem is nothing more than that if "Stop agitating yourself…" and "… comfort yourself (now)" belong together, what separates them should be a semicolon.

Either way, can you find anyone confident to support your "Is the sentence above have a correct grammar?"

Answer (score -1):

It is grammatical, but not natural.

First, the English for "agitate oneself" is "get agitated" (or more likely "get upset/bothered/anxious/flustered")

Secondly, the English for "comfort yourself" here is not even "get comforted", but "cheer up!".

Normally, "to comfort" is used only in the active sense of "do something to make somebody less unhappy". If you use the passive, or reflexive, it doesn't mean "become less unhappy", but "have somebody (or yourself) do something to you that makes you less unhappy".

Comment: Colin, could you justify all after 'the English for "agitate oneself" is "get agitated" (or more likely "get upset/bothered/anxious/flustered")', please?

For instance, don't you think the English for "comfort yourself" anywhere is far more likely "get comforted" than "cheer up!"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: no, I don't, though perhaps I shouldn't have been so categorical about it. The only meaning I can ascribe to "get comforted" is "go and find something or somebody that will comfort you" - a possible meaning, but unlikely in most contexts. For me, it cannot mean "cheer up".

Comment: For you, it cannot mean "cheer up"? Really? Then why did you post 'the English for "comfort yourself" here is not even "get comforted", but "cheer up!"'?

Comment: More imprecision on my part, @RobbieGoodwin (though I think you're being disingenuous). For "cannot mean", read "would not be used by a native English speaker to mean".

Comment: Up to you, Colin. To me, all that stops “Stop agitating yourself, comfort yourself now!” being (grammarly) correct is that I'd prefer a semi-colon instead of that comma.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I said at the beginning that it was grammatical. NIceties of punctuation are part of etiquette, and have very little to do with grammar.